# How to take a script from an HTML file and move it to it's own .JS file?

Tags: javascript, html, external, html-framework-7

I am trying to simplify my HTML file, and I have very long scripts that consist of just HTML (templates) that I'd like to move to their own external files. This is easy for me to do when the `<script>` tags involve functions, but in my case it's just straight HTML. In the new external file, how do I properly type up those HTML tags? See below.

```
    <script type="text/template7" id="myStuffTemplate">
  {{#each results}}
  <div class="list-block media-list">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="item-link item-content">
          <div class="item-media"><img src={{this.pictures['1']}} width="80" height="80px"></div>
          <div class="item-inner">
            <div class="item-title-row">
              <div class="item-title">{{this.name}}</div>
            </div>
            <div class="item-text">{{this.description}}</div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  {{else}}
  <div style="text-align:center">
    <h1>Nothing yet!</h1>
    <h2>Upload things you're willing to trade so you can start trading!</h2>
  </div>
  {{/each}}
</script>
```

That's the script within the HTML File. I'd like that moved into its own external file. How can one go about doing this? And do I reference it just like every other file when I link it? eg.:

```
<script type="text/template7"  src="js/views/mystuff.js" id="myStuffTemplate"></script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That looks like you're trying to use Handlebars or EJS, which would need to come from the server I believe.   Otherwise, you would simply stick into a .js file and change type to `text/javascript` and eliminate the id.

Comment: I'm using [Template7](http://idangero.us/template7/#.WCO6uJMrJTY) to do this.. which requires that `id` and `type`.  That's what's making this tricky. When the script is in the HTML file, it works perfectly. But when I move it into its own file, no luck.

Comment: Can you use a server side include?

Comment: I'm not sure what that means ^^^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a script, it's a template made with either handlebars or moustache templates.

You can't "source" them with `<script src="...">` like you can with Javascript, but they can be stored externally, then loaded and processed at runtime. This needs to be done asynchronously through an AJAX call. For example, assuming you were using jQuery, you could achieve it with the following:

```
// request the template
$.get('templates/products.hbs', function(rawTemplate) {
    // once received, convert the raw template to a handlebars template
    var template = Handlebars.compile(rawTemplate);
    // compile the template with your context 'data' and set it on an element with an id
    $('#someTargetId').html(template(data));
}, 'html'); // <-- tell jquery to load the file as html
```

Just be warned, even small templates will take some time to load, so there will be a delay between your page loading and the template loading then being displayed.

Comment: Great point. I definitely will need to pay attention to load speeds - This must be a [Template7](http://idangero.us/template7/#.WCO6uJMrJTY) limitation that I'll need to consider. My HTML file will just need to stay a bit longer I suppose, or I'll need to consider a different solution. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, consider using a framework like Angular.js or React.js however this should work for you:

Let's suppose that you want to put that inside a div with id=items: 
`<div id="items"> Your code... </div>`

1. In the html file add this, just before the `<body>` closing tag:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="code.js"></script>`
to include your code and this 
`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`
 to include jQuery.

2. Create a code.js file and put the following code inside:

   ```
   $(document).ready( function() {
       var myCode = "{{#each results}}" +
   "<div class="list-block media-list">" +
     "<ul>" +
       "<li>" +
         "<a href="#" class="item-link item-content">" +
           "<div class="item-media"><img src={{this.pictures['1']}} width="80" height="80px"></div>" +
           "<div class="item-inner">" +
             "<div class="item-title-row">" +
               "<div class="item-title">{{this.name}}</div>" +
             "</div>" +
             "<div class="item-text">{{this.description}}</div>" +
           "</div>" +
         "</a>" +
       "</li>" +
     "</ul>" +
   "</div>" +
   "{{else}} " +
   "<div style="text-align:center">" +
     "<h1>Nothing yet!</h1>" +
     "<h2>Upload things you're willing to trade so you can start trading!</h2>" +
   "</div>" +
   "{{/each}}";

   $( "#items" ).html( myCode );
   } );
   ```